# "Ходить налево"

Tags: фразеология

Почему хождением налево называют супружескую измену?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, ходить на сторону, по бабам/мужикам и проч. - самоочевидно. Так что слово ходить как евфемизм вполне понятно. А левая сторона в разных контекстах всегда символизировала что-то незаконное, грязное, грешное и противопоставлялась правой, правильной и праведной. 
Вот сам вопрос, почему именно такое отношение к сторонам (и даже рукам) появилось у многих и разных народов, не очень понятен. Хотя отдельные предположения есть. Например, в некоторых культурах левая рука (как менее сильная и значит - менее нужная) использовалась для туалетных надобностей.

Answer (score 1):

В христианстве считается, что Бог наделил человека свободой воли, но при этом снабдил его двумя советчиками - ангелом и демоном, которые за ним присматривают. В тех случаях, когда тому нужно принять важное решение, они посредством внутреннего голоса высказывают ему свои аргументы. При этом невидимый ангел находится за правым плечом, а невидимый демон - за левым. Отсюда и пошло всякий плохой поступок называть "левым". Например, "сбыть товар налево", "взять левую работёнку".

Comment: Это суеверие ничего общего с христианством не имеет.
Т.е. все бы ничего, но "левый-правый" за уши притянуто.

Я вас предупреждал, что буду удалеть личные послания?

Comment: Мне кажется, что в данном случае перепутаны причина и следствие. Данное верование к христианству действительно отношения не имеет, иначе можно было его подтвердить цитатой из Библии. А появилось оно как раз из тех соображений, что одна сторона левая, грешная. а другая правая, правильная. Есть другое аналогичное поверьте, что если просыпаешь соль, нужно кинуть три щепотки через левое плечо.

Comment: Трудно сказать... И плюнуть тоже через левое...
Но мне кажется, что оно, поверье это (на верование не тянет, верование - это система взлядов, "проторелигия") не просто не имеет отношения к христианству, но и прямо противоречит ему, за что и осуждаема. А коли так, то и такая версия появляения не очень как-то логична.

Comment: Все приведенные примеры - это не верования, а языческие суеверия, которые не признаются и даже осуждаются церковью. Насколько мне известно, хотя я не очень подкован в вопросах религии, церковь признает лишь некоторые языческие обряды, например праздник масленицы

Comment: Различие левого и правого настолько заметно в жизни человека, что не могло не стать символичным еще на ранних стадиях, до формирования развитых религий. Нашла такую [статью](http://www.mifinarodov.com/l/levyiy-i-pravyiy.html), но не знаю, авторитетный ли источник...

Answer (score 0):

Это присутствует и в Библии, вот отрывок:

От Матфея 25:31-46

Козлы и овцы

31 Когда Сын Человеческий придет в Своей славе и с Ним все ангелы, тогда Он сядет на престоле Своей славы. 32 Перед Ним будут собраны все народы, и Он отделит одних людей от других, как пастух отделяет овец от козлов. 33 Овец Он соберет по правую сторону от Себя, а козлов – по левую.

34 Тогда Царь скажет тем, кто по правую сторону: «Придите ко Мне, благословенные Моим Отцом, получите ваше наследство – Царство, приготовленное вам еще от создания мира. 35 Потому что Я был голоден, и вы накормили Меня; Я хотел пить, и вы напоили Меня; Я был странником, и вы приютили Меня. 36 Я был наг, и вы одели Меня; Я был болен, и вы ухаживали за Мной; Я был в темнице, и вы пришли навестить Меня». 37 Тогда праведные скажут: «Господи, когда это мы видели Тебя голодным и накормили Тебя? Когда Ты хотел пить, и мы дали Тебе напиться? 38 Когда мы видели Тебя странником и приютили Тебя, или видели нагим и одели? 39 Когда мы видели Тебя больным или в темнице и навестили Тебя?» 40 Царь им ответит: «Говорю вам истину: то, что вы сделали одному из наименьших Моих братьев, вы сделали Мне».

41 Тогда Он скажет и тем, кто будет по левую сторону: «Идите от Меня, проклятые, в вечный огонь, приготовленный для дьявола и его ангелов. 42 Потому что Я был голоден, и вы не накормили Меня; Я хотел пить, и вы не напоили Меня; 43 Я был странником, и вы не приютили Меня; Я был наг, и вы не одели Меня; Я был болен и в темнице, и вы не навестили Меня». 44 Они тоже спросят: «Господи, когда это мы видели Тебя голодным, или когда Ты хотел пить, или был странником, или нуждался в одежде, или был болен, или в темнице, и мы не помогли Тебе?» 45 Он им ответит: «Говорю вам истину: все, чего вы не сделали для одного из наименьших, вы не сделали Мне».

46 И они пойдут в вечное наказание, а праведники – в вечную жизнь.